# How to plot pdf of uniform random variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, probability-density

`x` and `y` have the uniform distribution and I want to plot pdf of `z` in Matlab.

```
x ~ U(0,1)

y ~ U(0,1)

Z = (-2.ln(x))^0.5  * cos(2.pi.y)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are X and Y independent?

Comment: Also, would you mind sharing the motivation for this interesting distribution?

Comment: Are you sure the `(-2.ln(x))` term is not to the power of 1/2 rather than 2? It might be worth checking.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The power is 0.5 and I type 2. I'm sorry

Comment: There is no information about independent of X and Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would take some time to derive the distribution for *Z* though it is probably easiest to start with the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) such as P(Z<=z) then condition on X=x or Y=y.  Not clear which will be easiest path to eventually get the explicit CDF or PDF. But P(Z<=z|X = x) or P(Z<=z|Y = y) seems best approach. Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is probably the best place to get the analytical derivation [in progress here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/372817).

Empirically this is easy to obtain and with a large enough sample size, it should work very well for many applications.

```
N = 5000;
X = rand(N,1);
Y = rand(N,1);
Z = cos(2*pi*Y).*(-2*log(X)).^2;

figure, hold on, box on
histogram(Z,'Normalization','pdf')
```

[image: Histogram of Z]

If you wanted to see `Z` as a function of `(X,Y)`, these might help.

```
n = 100;
x = linspace(0,1,n);
y = linspace(0,1,n);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = cos(2*pi*Y).*(-2*log(X)).^2;
```

The contour plot isn't very useful
[image: Contour Plot of Z]

But the surface plot shows a bit more what is going on based on `(X,Y)`
[image: Surface Plot of Z]

Comment: Thank you @SecretAgentMan . The power of ln was 0.5 . This is my fault to type power. thank you for your reply

Comment: Why the graph is the two-dimensional? Should not it be drawn in three dimensions?

Comment: @MasoudAbasian, the probability distribution of Z, `f_Z(z)` is a one dimensional function. I'm not sure the motivation for a higher dimensional plot but see my update and feel free to comment back based on your needs.

Comment: My previous comment says "probability distribution" which is unclear, based on my notation, I meant the probability density function (PDF).  However, the cumulative distribution function for Z, `F_Z(z)` is also a one dimensional function based on my representation.  Just wanted to clarify.